# Is there a way to get a gradient background with a NavigationView on top

Tags: swiftui, text, background, navigation, gradient

[This is what it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iSk8.png)
[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBAZi.png)
The problem is is that it is not showing any type of gradient beneath the NavigationView.

[I tried putting the gradient like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlID9.png)
[and this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqRJn.png). If you are wondering why there is not much code that would be because I just started the app.

Answer (score 0):

I think your order is wrong, having the `NavigationView` on top, makes it work.

```
NavigationView {
    ZStack {
        LinearGradient (gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.red, Color.blue]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
                
        NavigationLink(destination: CreateCustomLevelView(), label: {
            Text ("Create New")
                .padding (15)
                .background (Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor (Color.black)
                .cornerRadius (15)
            })
        }
    }
```